# CSS Page Layout issues: background repeat and footer positioning broken

Tags: html, css

I am trying to switch my web site over to CSS formatting and it is looking good except for two issues I am having with my page layout:

1) The background image of my left-most column is not repeating (although the background color extends the full length of the page) and

2) My copyright footer is appearing to the right of my two layout columns instead of at the bottom. I have tried every suggestion I can find but am having no luck with either problem!

The page and code can be seen here:
http://agdequine.com/About_Adam.html

(The plan is to eventually do away with the layout table currently in the main section but one thing at a time!)

Thanks!

Comment: You should get rid of the position: absolute. You just use floats and position: relative basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lpDKs

The tables should never be used to align content.
Using only floats, no absolute positioning.
The repeating background is on the main container which has 100% min-height.

Note: it still needs a lot of work. But this is the rough idea.

```
 html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}  
body {
  background-color:#597d4f;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 850px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color:#597d4f;
  background-image:url('http://agdequine.com/images/banner_top_02.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-origin:border-box;
}

.topframe {
  position: relative;
  height: 323px;
  background-color:#597d4f;
  background-image:url('http://agdequine.com/images/banner_top_01.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:border-box;

}

.leftframe {
  width:196px;
  float: left;
}

.mainframe {
  width: 654px;
  float: left;
  background-color:#faf4d1;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.title_main {
  font-size: 46px;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  color:#6f4e4a;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-left: 30px; 
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.nav_container {
  width: 196px;
  height: 190px;
  position: relative; 
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: rgba(167,192,74,0.4);
  }

.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 850px;
  margin: -80px auto 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4e3d41;
}
.footer p {
  text-align: right;
}

ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a.menuitem {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  font-size: 24px;
}
a.menuitem:link {color:#6f4e4a;}
a.menuitem:visited {color:#6f4e4a;}
a.menuitem:hover {text-decoration: underline;
}

a.main:link {color:#6f4e4a;}
a.main:visited {color:#4e3d41;}
a.main:hover {color:#FF0000;}
.image-cont {
  width:200px;
  position:relative; 
}
.img-left {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
.img-right {
  float: right; 
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
p.main {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#4e3d41;
}

p.largemain {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#4e3d41;
}

p.caption {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#4e3d41;
}

.emphasize {
  color:#FF0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The right sintax for the background positioning is without the `-` between values:

```
background-position: top left;
```

Then, the image is not extending vertically because you setted the positioning as absolute, so if you define the height as percentage, it will be as high as the content itself, and not the parent container.

Comment: Thank you! After making the suggested change, the repeat was fixed and it made another problem appear: my faux table included the page header. Fixing that issue by moving the container to include only the left and right columns in the main body also fixed the issue I was having with the footer not appearing.

Comment: @user3396385 Just remove `position: relative;` from `div.mainframe` and everything will look fine (also `left` and `top`are not anymore needed.

Comment: There is no need to set background-position as it is the default.BTW it is left top [horizontal pos :: vertical pos]